# Slow MySQL Query not using filesort

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a query on my homepage that is getting slower and slower as my database table grows larger.

tablename = tweets_cache
rows = 572,327

this is the query I'm currently using that is slow, over 5 seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM tweets_cache t WHERE t.province='' AND t.mp='0' ORDER BY t.published DESC LIMIT 50;
```

If I take out either the WHERE or the ORDER BY, then the query is super fast 0.016 seconds.

I have the following indexes on the tweets_cache table.

```
PRIMARY
published
mp
category
province
author
```

So i'm not sure why its not using the indexes since mp, provice and published all have indexes? Doing a profile of the query shows that its not using an index to sort the query and is using filesort which is really slow.

```
possible_keys = mp,province
Extra = Using where; Using filesort
```

I tried adding a new multie-colum index with "profiles & mp". The explain shows that this new index listed under "possible_keys" and "key", but the query time is unchanged, still over 5 seconds.

Here is a [screenshot](http://i355.photobucket.com/albums/r469/canadaka_bucket/slow_query_profile.png) of the profiler info on the query.

Something weird, I made a dump of my database to test on my local desktop so i don't screw up the live site. The same query on my local runs super fast, milliseconds. So I copied all the same mysql startup variables from the server to my local to make sure there wasn't some setting that might be causing this. But even after that the local query runs super fast, but the one on the live server is over 5 seconds.

My database server is only using around 800MB of the 4GB it has available.
here are the related my.ini settings i'm using

> default-storage-engine = MYISAM
> max_connections = 800
> skip-locking
> key_buffer = 512M
> max_allowed_packet = 1M
> table_cache = 512
> sort_buffer_size = 4M
> read_buffer_size = 4M
> read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
> myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
> thread_cache_size = 8
> query_cache_size = 128M
> # Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
> thread_concurrency = 8
> # Disable Federated by default
> skip-federated
>
> key_buffer = 512M
> sort_buffer_size = 256M
> read_buffer = 2M
> write_buffer = 2M
>
> key_buffer = 512M
> sort_buffer_size = 256M
> read_buffer = 2M
> write_buffer = 2M

MySQL 5.0.67

```
CREATE TABLE `tweets_cache` (                                                             
            `id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',                                          
            `published` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',                                               
            `title` varchar(140) NOT NULL,                                                          
            `category` varchar(50) NOT NULL,                                                        
            `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,                                                            
            `author` varchar(25) NOT NULL,                                                          
            `author_full` varchar(150) NOT NULL,                                                    
            `hash` varchar(50) NOT NULL,                                                            
            `lastupdate` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',                                              
            `avatar` varchar(120) NOT NULL,                                                         
            `mp` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',                                                       
            `followers` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',                                               
            `province` varchar(2) NOT NULL,                                                         
            `talkback` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',                                             
            `in_reply_to_status_id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',                       
            `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',                                               
            `tracked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',                                              
            `geo` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',                                                  
            PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),                                                                    
            KEY `published` (`published`),                                                          
            KEY `mp` (`mp`),                                                                        
            KEY `category` (`category`),                                                            
            KEY `province` (`province`),                                                            
            KEY `author` USING BTREE (`author`),                                                    
            KEY `home` (`province`,`mp`,`published`)                                                
          ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC COMMENT='InnoDB free: 275456 kB'
```

Comment: what version of MySql are you using. Please also drop a "show create table" definition here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> i'm not sure why its not using the indexes since mp, provice and published all have indexes?

MySQL will only use one index across the table. If you want to do a WHERE and an ORDER BY in the same step, create a compound index containing the matching conditions on the left with the ordering conditions on the right, eg. in this case `(province, mp, published)`.

About [ORDER BY optimisation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Comment: OMG thank you, i added "published" to the multicolumn index and now the query takes 0.015 seconds!

So all the indexes I have for single columns like "mp,provice" are kind of useless since there is always an ORDER BY in my queries?

Comment: They're not *totally* useless; if `mp` didn't exist, queries based just on `mp` with order-by would be even slower! But yes, having lots of single-column indexes tends not to help as much as you'd think.

Comment: so would it be better to turn all my indexes into multicolumn indexes since I always order by published.
for example turn "mp" into "mp,published"

Comment: Yes. A compound index also serves the purpose of indexing a left-subset, ie. if you created an index on `(province, mp)` you could index a query on `WHERE province=`, but not `WHERE mp=`.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the query on two pieces, so both indexes can work, something like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cache
SELECT -describefields- FROM tweets_cache t WHERE t.province='' AND t.mp='0';

SELECT * FROM cache c ORDER BY c.published DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Temporary tables can not have (and use) indices in MySQL.